# Don't read the JSON Object in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I have some problem to get json object...

I send a json object to localhost(node.js server).

When node.js server received the json object, parsed json object has 'undefined
 type.

For that reason, I checked the json object but it has not structure problem..

How can I solve this problem?

Thank in advance!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:62590/saveResource",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    success: function (data) {
       ............
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

===========================================================================

```
app.post('/saveResource', function (request, response) {

    var resultObj = request.body;
    var object = resultObj.requestInfo;
    console.log(typeof(object)); -> 'undefined' type
});
```

===========================================================================

```
* node.js server reveceive the following object.


{
  "requestInfo": {
    "urlInformation": "data",
    "methodInformation": "GET",
    "bodyInformation": "data",
    "headerInformation": []
  }
}
```

Comment: For God's sake, people, stop stringifying JSON. Just work with plain JSON data. Send JSON, receive JSON, read JSON. Why do you convert it to string? You're trying to read the `requestInfo` property of a _string_, not an object. Remove `JSON.stringify`, job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jeremy-thille already answered the question, but to be more clear just change

```
dataType: "text"
```

to

```
dataType: "json"
```

And remove the JSON.stringify call....